# Creality CR-10 slightly jerks when moves from right to left

Tags: print-quality, calibration, creality-cr-10

So when CR-10 prints square ([like on the video starting from 6 second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPSg3x6hxFA&feature=youtu.be)) while being in the top right corner extruder jerks i.e. slightly moves to the right and then continues movement to the left. So the resulting prints are not so nice:
[image]
What can I do? I don't see issues in assembling but I almost definitely have them. What can be wrong?

**UPDATE**: Printer settings: nozzle temperature - 180, bed temperature - 65. I calibrated extuder according to the video. Bed level seems to be ok for me. I started using Difamix because of bed adhesion (sometimes even using IKEA mirror).

Here is my calibration cube size (I wrote only edges different from 20mm):

[image: calibration cube size]

And here is the issues with calibration cube I found. Top layer:
[image: Top layer] 
Bottom layer:
[image: Bottom layer]
Layer with Y is a bit rough (not a big issue as for me):
[image: Layer with Y]
Also edge between X layer and Y layer is not very sharp, a bit rounded.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing!

Comment: The calibration cube with +/- 0.5 mm is still in the acceptable range. You can tune that later, by adjusting the steps/mm AFTER ensuring the filament feedrate is correct. The first figure is the important one, and I havent seen this before. Does reducing or enhancing the voltage on the stepper driver change this pattern? Is there a mechanical resistance or even noise along this axis if the printer is off and you move it by hand? Is the temperature on the nozzle stable?

Comment: i would try tightening the screws and belts, it helped a lot on mine

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the nozzle is not perfectly perpendicular to the bed. It is also dragging which might indicate overextrusion or bad z stop calibration..

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer. How can z stop be calibrated?

Comment: @tiktak Your nozzle is too far from the bed, you need to adjust the endstop or use the leveling screws to get the nozzle closer to the bed. Also calibrate the extruder to get rid of the over-extrusion.